# Colcon/Ros2: Specify a different src directory?

Tags: ros2, colcon

From the documentation, I see that colcon allows one to specify different build (`--build-base`) and install directories (`--install-base`):

https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/reference/verb/build.html

But is it also possible to specify a different src directory? or is the name `src` hardcoded? It seems like there should be an option like `--src-base`, but I don't see that anywhere in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`colcon build --paths <package_path>`](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/reference/discovery-arguments.html).

The `--build-base` will change the path where the `build` folder from the workspace will be placed.